# Selenium 3 doesn't work with faked camera arguement from ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, selenium3

I am using Cucumber with Selenium Webdriver v2.53 and ChromeDriver v2.24 in Ruby and everything works smoothly. Now I am trying to upgrade Selenium Webdriver to v3.0.5 then I find that the old settings for ChromeOptions (I use a faked camera option from Chrome) doesn't work with new Selenium Webdriver 3. 
Below is my exising settings:

## env.rb

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new
  caps["chromeOptions"] = {}
  caps["chromeOptions"]["args"] = %W(
        --no-sandbox
        --disable-plugins
        --use-fake-device-for-media-stream
        --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
        --start-maximized
        --disable-notifications
    )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps)
end
```

I need to have this faked camera option in Selenium 3, so if anyone knows how to fix it or ideas about how to fix it, please help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work", does it raise an error, does it just not do what you expect?

Comment: It just doesn't work. When I watch for the browser, I see it displays the popup to 'Block or Accept using Camera' instead of using the faked one